# MySQL fetch data from another table where the column row matches a row result from first table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, let's say they contain:

**Table1**

```
id | username

1  | Bla
4  | Bla2
```

**Table2**

```
FROM_ID | FK_TOID | Action

1       | 2       | -1
4       | 2       | -1
```

Now all I have is something like:

```
SELECT FK_FROMID FROM table2 WHERE FK_TOID = 2 AND FP_ACTION = -1
```

What I want to do is fetch the id and username from table1, where the id of table1 matches FROM_ID from table2, where FK_TOID is '2' in table2.

So basically the results returned should be something like

`[{ id: 1, FK_FROMID: 1, username: Bla }, { id: 4, FK_FROMID: 4, username: Bla2 }]`

Comment: So basically the results returned should be something like `[{ id: 1, FK_FROMID: 1, username: Bla }, { id: 4, FK_FROMID: 4, username: Bla2 }]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***you need this:***

```
SELECT A.id,B.from_id as FK_FROMID,A.username
FROM t1 A
LEFT JOIN t2 B
ON A.id=B.from_id
```

***click this link to see the result:***

***http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/868c1/4***

***update:1***

```
    SELECT A.id,B.from_id as FK_FROMID,A.username
    FROM t1 A
    LEFT JOIN t2 B
    ON A.id=B.from_id 
    WHERE B.fk_toid=2 AND B.action=-1;
```

***check this link:***

***http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/868c1/8***

Comment: Hi -- the table2 condition `WHERE FK_TOID = 2 AND FP_ACTION = -1` isn't there, is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the inner join or left outer join (does not matter for your example) as follows:

```
select t1.id, t2.FK_FROMID, t1.username 
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 
on (t2.FROM_ID = t1.id)
where t2.FK_VOID = 2 
and t2.FP_ACTION = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.from_id 
where table2.TOID = '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to use any joins for this. A simple query will work as follows:

```
select t1.id, t2.FK_FROMID, t1.username 
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2 
where t1.id = t2.FK_FROMID
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi -- where do I fit the `WHERE FK_TOID = 2 AND FP_ACTION = -1` for the table2 condition? Thanks